# django: request.user is an int, not a User object

Tags: django

I'm using django 1.0 and have a method in views.py that starts out like this:

```
def my_view(request, org_id):
    a = request.user.is_staff() #this line has error
    #more code...
```

When I try to load the page, I receive the error "'int' object is not callable" on the line marked above.  My models.py file does contain a "User" object which is imported at the top of views.py, but removing this import statement from views.py does not seem to prevent this error.  Is it possible that this other User class is causing a conflict in another one of my files, perhaps?  Do you have any other ideas regarding what could possibly be causing this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess the problem is `is_staff()`. Try

```
a = request.user.is_staff
```

`is_staff` is a field of the model. But it is boolean. Nevertheless it could be that it is stored as `int` internally.

[User model documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/topics/auth/#topics-auth)

Comment: +1 - and, in case anyone is wondering why a field called `is_staff` would be an integer, it's actually defined as a boolean but certain database backends return ints for boolean fields. Makes no difference in Python anyway.

Comment: Thanks, Felix!  I can't believe I missed that!

Comment: Very often the small and simple things are those that make you crazy ;)